# USB disk/SD card not remounted when resuming from suspend

Tags: usb, mount, suspend, fstab

I have an external USB disk which is an SD card I keep in the card reader permanently and mounted in fstab. It has worked fine. However, it is not remounted after waking up from suspend. How can I get it mounted again when returning from suspend? The only way I have found is very hacky and causes some problems. I run a script containing:

cd /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd
echo -n "0000:00:14.0" > unbind
echo -n "0000:00:14.0" > bind

0000:00:14.0 is the USB device and I simply unbind/bind the device which results in it being mounted as it should. I run this script through systemd and it works, but there must be a better way since my other disks is mounted when I wake up from suspend.

Comment: The other disk is external? Does the disk shutdown during suspend or do you have an external supplier for it?

Comment: I guess I wasn't being specific enough. It's a SD card in my SD card reader, but I use it all the time and never remove it. I will update my original post. The problem is the same though.

Comment: Ok, this does not change my question. Does the adapter shut down during suspend or do you have an external power source supplier for it?

Comment: The adapter is a SD card slot built into the laptop so I am not sure whether it shuts down. I hope I am understanding you correctly.

Comment: I would also like to add that in ElementaryOS the SD card is remounted after waking from suspend, so this problem seems to be Ubuntu/Unity related.